# How to properly fit data to a power law in Python?

Tags: python, r, math, statistics, power-law

I am considering the [number of occurrence of unique words in the Moby Dick novel](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/%7Eaaronc/powerlaws/data.htm) and using the [`powerlaw` python package](https://pythonhosted.org/powerlaw/) to fit words’ frequencies to a power law.

I am not sure why I can't recapitulate the results from previous work by Clauset et al. as both the p-value and the KS score are "bad".

The idea is to fit the frequencies of unique words into a power law. However, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests for goodness of fit calculated by `scipy.stats.kstest` look terrible.

I have the following function to fit data to a power law:

```
import numpy as np
import powerlaw
import scipy
from scipy import stats

def fit_x(x):
    fit = powerlaw.Fit(x, discrete=True)
    alpha = fit.power_law.alpha
    xmin  = fit.power_law.xmin
    print('powerlaw', scipy.stats.kstest(x, "powerlaw", args=(alpha, xmin), N=len(x)))
    print('lognorm', scipy.stats.kstest(x, "lognorm", args=(np.mean(x), np.std(x)), N=len(x)))
```

---

Downloading the frequency of unique words in the novel Moby Dick by Herman Melville (supposed to follow a power law according to Aaron Clauset et al.):

```
wget http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/data/words.txt
```

Python script:

```
x =  np.loadtxt('./words.txt')
fit_x(x)
```

results:

```
('powerlaw', KstestResult(statistic=0.862264651286131, pvalue=0.0))
('log norm', KstestResult(statistic=0.9910368602492707, pvalue=0.0))
```

---

When I compare the expected results and follow this [R tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/b_powerlaw_examples.pdf) on the same Moby Dick dataset I get a decent p-value and KS test value:

```
library("poweRlaw")
data("moby", package="poweRlaw")
m_pl = displ$new(moby)
est = estimate_xmin(m_pl)
m_pl$setXmin(est)
bs_p = bootstrap_p(m_pl)
bs_p$p
## [1] 0.6738
```

---

What am I missing when computing the KS test values and postprocessing the fit by the [powerlaw](https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw) python library? The PDF and CDF look ok to me, but the KS tests look awry.

[image]

Comment: The Karate Club network is fairly small. I don't think you have enough samples in there to make very strong statistical statements.

Comment: Also, in my experience, people often use the term powerlaw fairly loosely to mean any distribution where the histogram counts on a log-log plot form a line for some range of the data, where the linear part rarely covers the whole range of the data. Hence when you run the KS-test, you might get a low score even for samples from the literature.

Comment: Final fun fact: a random subsample from a powerlaw distribution will not be distributed according to a powerlaw. Hence any claim in the literature that empirical distribution x follows a powerlaw is inherently wrong (the parent distribution must have much thicker tails than expected for a powerlaw distribution if the distribution of the subsample is to follow a powerlaw distribution).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen From the website the author linked to: https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062 "Power-law distributions in empirical data", the paper is talking about how "Commonly used methods for analyzing power-law data, such as least-squares fitting, can produce substantially inaccurate estimates of parameters for power-law distributions, and even in cases where such methods return accurate answers they are still unsatisfactory because they give no indication of whether the data obey a power law at all."  However, I'm not sure what's happening with the results here

Comment: [Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15140) is a recent article from a reputable journal stating the result on power-law sampling. The result itself though is much older (and for some reason continuous to be not too well known).

Comment: I wasn't not trying to point to a solution to your fitting problem, I was just referencing the theorem (on page 2 of the pdf): "Power-laws or scale-free distributions, despite their name, are not invariant under subsampling. Namely, if P(s) follows a power-law distribution, then P_{sub}(s) is not a power law [...]" I think this theorem has important implications for the interpretation of many results published in the literature (quite damning, usually), and should caution you to over-interpret any scale-freeness you might think you might be observing in your own data.

Comment: To fit your scalar and exponent, I would plot the degree counts on a log-log plot and eyeball the parameters from the straight portion of the graph.

Comment: related: https://asaip.psu.edu/Articles/beware-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not clear to me how to determine significance and goodness of fit by using the `scipy.stats.kstest` with the `powerlaw` library.

Though, `powerlaw`  implements its own [`distribution_compare`](https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw/blob/06e3f0315f26819f26b847d9bbe7e0885c2b4ca1/powerlaw.py#L314) capability which returns the [likelihood ratio](https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw/blob/06e3f0315f26819f26b847d9bbe7e0885c2b4ca1/powerlaw.py#L1803) `R` and the `p-val` of `R` (see some content from Aaron Clauset on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266070/comparing-power-law-with-other-distributions)):

> R : float
> Loglikelihood ratio of the two distributions' fit to the data. If
> greater than 0, the first distribution is preferred. If less than
> 0, the second distribution is preferred.
>
> p : float
> Significance of R

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import urllib
import powerlaw

urllib.urlretrieve('https://raw.github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw/master/manuscript/words.txt', 'words.txt')
words = genfromtxt('words.txt')

fit = powerlaw.Fit(words, discrete=True)

print(fit.distribution_compare('power_law', 'exponential', normalized_ratio=True))
(9.135914718776998, 6.485614241379581e-20)
print(fit.distribution_compare('power_law', 'truncated_power_law'))
(-0.917123083373983, 0.1756268316869548)
print(fit.distribution_compare('power_law', 'truncated_power_law'))
(-0.917123083373983, 0.1756268316869548)
print(fit.distribution_compare('power_law', 'lognormal'))
(0.008785246720842022, 0.9492243713193919)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pay attention to whether the data is continuous or discrete, and then choose the appropriate test method; in addition, as the former said, the size of the data will have a certain impact on the result, I hope it will help you